# I'd like to make an internal grid view added by clicking the button on the external recyclerview

Tags: java, android

I want to make an internal grid view(room) added by clicking the button on the external recycler view(floor). but Null pointer extension occurs in onBindViewHolder. please help me

```
public class FloorAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements OnFloorItemClickListener {

    OnFloorItemClickListener listener;
    static public ArrayList<FloorData> floors;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener = null;

    public FloorAdapter(ArrayList<FloorData> floors, Context context) {
        this.floors = floors;
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(View v, int pos);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.mListener = listener ;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.signle_floor, parent, false);
        return new GridViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ((GridViewHolder)holder).recyclerView.setAdapter(new RoomAdapter(context, floors.get(position).rooms));
        ((GridViewHolder)holder).recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 2));
        ((GridViewHolder)holder).recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        ((GridViewHolder)holder).tvFloorNum.setText(String.valueOf(floors.get(position).floorNum));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return floors.size();
    }

    @Override public void onItemClick(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, View view, int position) {
        if(listener != null){
            listener.onItemClick(holder,view,position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return floors.get(position).id;
    }

    public class GridViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        TextView tvFloorNum;
        Button btnPlusRoom;

        public GridViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            recyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rvRooms);
            tvFloorNum = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvRoomNumber);
            btnPlusRoom = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlusRoom);
            btnPlusRoom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                    {
                        if(mListener != null){
                            mListener.onItemClick(v, pos);
                        }

                    }
                }

            });
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class RoomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoomAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<RoomData> rooms;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public RoomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RoomData> rooms) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rooms = rooms;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_room, parent, false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RoomData room = rooms.get(position);
        holder.tvRoomNum.setText(String.valueOf(room.roomNum));
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return rooms.size();
    }


    public static class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvRoomNum;

        public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvRoomNum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvRoomNumber);

        }
    }
}
```

```
public class RoomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView rvFloor;
    private FloorAdapter floorAdapter;
    public ArrayList<FloorData> globalfloors;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_room);


        globalfloors = prepareData();

        rvFloor = findViewById(R.id.rvFloors);

        floorAdapter = new FloorAdapter(globalfloors, RoomActivity.this);
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(RoomActivity.this);
        rvFloor.setLayoutManager(manager);
        rvFloor.setAdapter(floorAdapter);


        floorAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new FloorAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
                FloorData floor = globalfloors.get(position);
                RoomData newRoom = new RoomData();
                floor.finalRoomNum++;
                newRoom.roomNum = floor.finalRoomNum;
                floor.rooms.add(newRoom);
                rvFloor.setAdapter(floorAdapter);
            }
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<FloorData> prepareData() {
        ArrayList<FloorData> floors = new ArrayList<FloorData>();

        //첫번째 subject 추가
        FloorData floor1 = new FloorData();
        floor1.floorNum = 1;

        RoomData room101 = new RoomData();
        room101.roomNum = 101;

        RoomData room102 = new RoomData();
        room102.roomNum = 102;

        RoomData room103 = new RoomData();
        room103.roomNum = 103;

        floor1.finalRoomNum = 103;
        floor1.rooms.add(room101);
        floor1.rooms.add(room102);
        floor1.rooms.add(room103);
        floors.add(floor1);

        FloorData floor2 = new FloorData();
        floor2.floorNum = 2;
        floor2.finalRoomNum = 200;

        floors.add(floor2);
        return floors;
    }
}
```

activity_room

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".tools.RewardActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar_room"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:title="호실 등록"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvFloors"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

single_floor

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFloorNum"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPlusRoom"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="+"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:columnCount="5"
            android:id="@+id/rvRooms"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

single_room

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRoomNumber"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="30dp"

            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

error message describes "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at com.eos.parcelnoticemanager.tools.FloorAdapter.onBindViewHolder"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GridViewHolder` inside your `FloorAdapter` is pointing to the wrong XML Id tag for the TextView that's why it's throwing `NullPointerException`

Change this in your `GridViewHolder`

```
 tvFloorNum = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvRoomNumber);
```

to this

```
 tvFloorNum = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFloorNumber);
```

Then it should work

Comment: I miss it! Thank you so much:)